# Changing Page Layout without changing record type on Record Detail page

Tags: page-layout

can i change Page layout without changing record type on update of a field(may be a workflow field update or field update on a button click and gets updated from apex class)  on record detail page?

Answer (score 1):

I think lightning has some features you can take advantage for something like that ([for example](https://theaccidentaladmins.com/conditional-record-detail-components)).

### Use Cases for Lightning Features:

1. Eliminate the need for Account Record Types: If the only reason you
   want to create a new record type is to display different fields,
   simplify your build, stick with a -Master- record type, but use
   conditional components + quick actions to display editable field
   components based on the Account.
2. Display fields to specific users only: Minimize the use of page
   layouts by profile, instead use the current user’s record to
   conditionally display fields in a related record component.  To
   understand how to reference the current user, [see this post](https://theaccidentaladmins.com/filter-by-current-user-in-salesforce).
3. Lock Fields: Create two quick actions with the same fields on it,
   marking the fields on the page layout for one action as read only,
   while allowing the others to be edited.  You can now display the
   fields and allow them to be edited based on the record status and
   then display the read only fields when you would like them to be
   ‘locked.’  You can prevent annoying users with validation rules and
   also avoid issues with integration and data uploads that may
   conflict with validation rules.
4. And more:  I can come up with a dozen more, but hopefully this is
   enough to stir your imagination and I would love to see your ideas
   in the comments below!

### Classic

In classic the answer is a pretty blunt no. You'd have to create a fully custom VF page.

Comment: Remember though, using quick actions here does not really change the original details layouts. Instead you can utilize those as different components and set their visibility as required. These cannot be utilized if the requirement is to change the actual details layout altogether, which can be only done using record types. Something you may like to add in your answer.

Comment: Would it be possible (I'm not super experienced in lightning unfortunately) to minimize the layout and build a page almost exclusively out of components? Would that get a bit closer to what the op wants?

Comment: Could be possibly. But you still need to have the Details tab (if you are using Tabs component here) because the actual Edit operation works only on the primary page layout which is in the Details tab. All other quick action components use inline editing. An approach could be to keep minimal common fields in the actual page layout and then split the fields out as quick actions in different components and utilize the visibility option. But again if Tabs component is used, you cannot really hide the tabs itself but only the component within that tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically change the standard record detail page layout based on a particular condition, the answer is you **cannot** do so. You will need to have a record type and corresponding page layout for that purpose.

However, as its mentioned in the other [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/230744/54851), you can utilize the quick action approach if you can group your fields those need to be shown/hidden based on different conditions. Few things to note here if you follow that approach:

- You will need to add the quick actions as different Related Record components on your lighting page
- If you are using the standard Tabs component on your Lightning Page, you will still need to keep the Details tab, as the standard Edit button invokes an edit operation for the fields on the Details tab, which in turn is associated to your page layout
- With this approach, you can set the visibility of the quick action components based on your field values (refer below for example)

Your Lighting Page will then look like something as below (the screenshot is just for representation, the component out there should be associated to the respective quick action and the visibility set accordingly)
 [image]